# Solving $n/\ln (n) = 990,000$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, logarithms, lambert-w

I need to solve the non-linear equation $n/ \ln(n) = 990,000$, which is the approximation of the $990,000$th prime number. This is what I tried:

$n = 990,000 ( \ln (n)) $ (Multiply both sides by $\ln(n)$)

$\frac{n}{990,000} = \ln(n)$

$e^{n/990,000} = e ^ {\ln(n)}$

$n = e^{n/990,000}$

So then I went here: https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/index.php#nth

And found the 990,000 prime number is: $15,318,907$

So I plugged that in for n:

$990, 000\text{th prime} = e^{15,318,907/990000}$

$15,318,907 \neq 3803815.32$

But clearly the numbers are not equal, I'm not sure what I've done wrong, or how to go about getting an approximate answer for $n$, I need to find the answer mathematically using that formula.

Comment: $e^{15,318,907/990000}$ is not even close to $3803815.32$, it's more of a $5249500$. Anyway if you check the approximation before you took the exponential ($15318907/990,000 \approx \ln 15318907$) you can see it works quite well. Just the error increases after exponentiation...

Comment: Also, notice that you can use the prime number theorem to derive approximation formula for $n$-th prime (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Approximate_Value_of_Nth_Prime_Number).

Comment: From comments on the answers, this is a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You want an approximation to the nth prime (see this question: [Is there a way to find the approximate value of the nth prime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042717/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-approximate-value-of-the-nth-prime)).  But your question is about a single potential solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the equation ${n \over \ln n} = b$ is the Product Log or [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), so for this problem $n\to -990000\ W_{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{990000}\right) \approx 1.64497 10^7$.  The 990000th prime (found by common computer search) is $15318907 \approx 1.53 \times 10^7$.

Comment: how did you go from 1.644 ^ 7 to 1.53 * 10 ^ 7?

Comment: As in, how did you figure out the prime number here. Did I miss a step in your solution?

Comment: I didn't go from $1.644 \times 10^7$ to $1.53 \times 10^7$.  The solution to the nonlinear equation is merely an *approximation*.  Of course no formula gives an exact value for a prime.  (Whoever found such a formula would win a Field's Medal and change mathematics forever.)

Comment: So How would I get 1.53 x 10^7 if I didn't know the answer was 15318907?How would I find the approximate answer myself, without knowing the answer is 15318907.

Comment: @rrrrrr, there are a variety of ways.  Inverting the Riemann R function (e.g. binary search with R) is the most accurate -- it gives 15318519 for your example, which is quite close.  You can also invert li (the logarithmic integral) with or without a second sqrt(n) term.  You can average the upper and lower bounds from Dusart 2010, Axler 2013, or Axler 2017.  You can use the Cipolla 1902 asymptotic formula.

Answer (score 1):

$n/\ln(n)=990,000$ is not a approximation of the 990,000th prime number!

If you define the function $\pi(n)$ which gives the number of primes less than or equal to $n$, then 
$$ \pi(n)\sim \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$

Comment: How do I find the prime number using that function?

Comment: Why do you think you can?

Comment: Because my assignment says I need to using n/ln (n) :/

Comment: You assignment says to actually find the 990,000th prime number????

Comment: Yep, we have to find it using that formula or a formula that's more efficient.

Comment: Drop this course and take another.

Comment: Well he wants a approximation more than anything, is that not doable?

Answer (score 1):

The prime counting function $\frac {n}{\ln n}$ says that there are about $\frac {n}{\ln n}$ prime numbers less than $n.$

so if you have say that there are $990,000$ prime numbers less than 15 odd million

Then we would hope to see that
$\frac {15,318,907}{\ln (15,308,907)} \approx 990,000$

In fact:

$\frac {15,318,907}{\ln (15,308,907)} \approx 925,916$  giving about 7% error.

Which ties out with this table.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: How do I get the 15million without using that site? I need to find the number using the formula, or some other formula.